# Find a sinusoid in a sensor data

Tags: sensor, signal, signal-processing

I am collecting raw data from a radar sensor using source code from the manufacturing company to allow me to plot data.

I am looking for a repetitive movement that would be considered sinusoidal.

[image: Amplitude-Position Graph of Object Detection]

The image above shows a pulse bounced back indicating where the object is located. The pulse after it is the signal being bounced from a ceiling.

Questions:

1. Can I perform the Fast Fourier Transform or does it have to be plotted in terms of time?
2. Is there a better way to find repetitive movement over a period of time?

Comment: Why do you suggest that on a single event the distribution would be sinusoid? That would mean the object is reflecting in a strange way. You should first determine the position of the object with the data you have there and then plot the position you get over time to see a movement of the object.

Comment: yes,I meat after getting the position along a period of time if the object have a repetitve movement, it should show up as a sinusiod like movement! right?. so can I fft the data to get a sinusoid?

Comment: FFT is typically used to reduce code complexity in your code, which doesn't really make sense here. A simple CFT would be more applicable. As @Arsenal said, there is no mention of reoccurring position. I don't see any behavior that tells me that your object is moving back and forth. Rather, this graph looks like it's just detecting an object and depending on where the object is, your radar is getting an amplitude of signal. (I edited your question by the way, to make everything look nicer)

Comment: So in other words, how can we interpret this data to demonstrate that the object is moving back and forth? **For movement to be sinusoidal, there has to be an indication of a change of position depending on time itself.** That's why we can't interpret any sinusoidal movement with this graph that you have presented us.

Answer (score 1):

Your plot above indicates position, I assume from a single reading (?).  Your goal is to measure motion, which involves multiple position measurements.  If you determine position on a regular interval, and then plot the position over time, your sinusoid should show up if it's significantly greater than the position uncertainty.

If, on the other hand, the above graph represents the reflections from multiple readings, you may be able to find the statistical distribution of a sinusoidal signal within it.

Comment: the graph shows the position from single reading. If I recorded the the position for a period of time, I will see multiple position changes for multiple objects. If the position change og the object I am looking for is 0.2 m. How can I seach for it?. I know it have low frequency and it will be repetitive. can I assume it will be a sinusoid?

Comment: If you know the approximate distance to the object, you could sort the data for reflections falling into that range.  The movement may not be sinusoidal, but if it's periodic you should be able to find the fundamental.  Placing the object at a distance that clearly differentiates it from other sources of reflection, preferably closer, can help as well.